# Need help understanding how to pop stack with add esp, 12

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have a question about this assembly program:

```
extern printf                ; the C function, to be called

SECTION .data                ; Data section, initialized variables
a: dd 5                      ; int a=5;
fmt: db "a=%d, eax=%d",10,0  ; The printf format, '\n','0'

SECTION .text                ; Code section.

global main                  ; the standard gcc entry point
main:                        ; the program label for the entry point

push ebp                  ; calling convention
mov ebp, esp

mov eax, [a]              ; put a from store into register
add eax, 2                ; a+2
push eax                  ; value of a+2
push dword [a]            ; value of variable a
push dword fmt            ; address of ctrl string
call printf               ; Call C function
add  esp, 12              ; pop stack 3 times = 4 bytes

mov esp, ebp              ; returning convention
pop ebp                   ; same as "leave" op

mov eax,0                 ; normal (no error) return value
ret                       ; return
```

I see that near the end it pops the stack 3 times which is equal to 4 bytes. However, I do not understand why the stack needs to be popped at the end, and how 12 is equivalent to "3 times = 4 bytes" Also, is it necessary that the stacked be popped at the end?

Comment: 3 times = 12 bytes, which is why it's `add esp, 12`.  That comment is bogus.

Comment: And no, it's not necessary in *this* case.  The `mov esp, ebp` already takes care of that.

Comment: maybe it was supposed to say "3 times 4 bytes", i.e. 3*4 = 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call a (sub)function, the CPU needs to save the value where to jump back; it uses the stack for this

so when you enter the function, the topmost value on the stack is the return address

this code adds another 12 bytes to the stack

```
push eax                  ; value of a+2
push dword [a]            ; value of variable a
push dword fmt            ; address of ctrl string
```

each of these push writes 4 bytes to [ESP], and subtracts 4 byes of ESP (subtraction because the stack is growing downwards). Before you can `ret` back to your callee, you have to get rid of these 12 bytes on the stack. the easies way is, what he did in his code:

```
add  esp, 12              ; pop stack 3 times = 4 bytes
```

on the other hand, the function saves the current ESP in EBP right on top of the function (this creates a new 'stack frame')

```
push ebp                  ; calling convention
mov ebp, esp
```

this is done to be able to adress the callee's function parameters and local variables you may have reserved place for [EBP +/- offset], AND it's making you able to restore the whole stack by just loading the former value again:

```
mov esp, ebp              ; returning convention
pop ebp                   ; same as "leave" op
```

Note: in this code, the stack is cleaned up twice. ( add 12 to ESP (which cleans the stack from the values the syscall got as parameters), and again by loading previous value from EBP. In this case one of either is not needed